# Configure Grails Mail Plugin with Postfix

Tags: grails, smtp, postfix-mta

I am trying to use Grails Mail plugin http://grails.org/plugin/mail and Postfix https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-12-04. I can send email out by using "sendMail" in Linux. But I am having difficulties to configure the Mail plugin to work with it.

Does anybody have experience about this? Or do you have another good solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: It's so sad that 3 years later I need an answer for this and there is none.

Answer (score 0):

In grails-app/conf/application.yml place the following settings

```
grails:
 mail:
      host: "yourDomain.com"
      username: "username@yourDomain.com"
      password: "your-password"
      props:
          mail.smtp.auth: "true"
          mail.smtp.socketFactory.port: "465"
```

That's it... For me it works with Grails 3.3, using the plugin org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0 and Postfix version 3.3